# Sqlcommand going cahtch

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqlcommand

I got exception after result. Why is `sqlcomm` trying to find `doTable` default table string 'blTableName'? I'm not sending anywhere this name to `sqlcomm` so I need to see `sqlcomm` executed SQL query.

It is add parameter to database to 'TableName' table but anyway exception, not returning 1

```
string t_table_name = "TableName";

try
{
    BindingList<doTable> bl = new 
    daTable().getTable(CoreStatic.s_SqlServerConfigLocal, new doTable() { table_ = t_table_name, TablePK = p_doWcfTicketQueue.TablePK, TableBFK = 
    CoreStatic.s_CurrentBPK }, Enums.DynamicType.BindingList);

    foreach (doTable item_odoTable in bl)
    { 
        SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(blabla);
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("TableUpdate", SqlConn);

        SqlConn.Open();

        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() 
        { ParameterName = "@table", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = t_table_name });
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() 
        { ParameterName = "@TablePK", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = item_odoTable.TablePK });
        //is that possible to see sqlcomm sql query? like" insert into TableName... bla bla "

        result = sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}//try
catch (SqlException exc)
{
   //exc = invalid object name 'blTableName'
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `TableUpdate` SP?

Comment: exception message = "Invalid object name 'blTableName'."
SP = 
@table(nvharchar(128),Input , No default)
@TablePK(uniqueidentifier,Input , No default)

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  There is an explorer in the tool that lets you see the tables and the stored procedures.  You need to look at the stored procedure TableUpdate in the database.

Comment: Are you using parameters to query a specific table? This usually doesn't work at all. Could you show the code of the Stored Procedure? And no, if the query code is inside the stored procedure you cannot see it in C# but you need some kind of administrative tool that let you load your procedure code and edit it

Comment: not it is not a specific table
string t_table_name = "TableName"; is for example. its original changing every day dynamicly

Comment: I'm using ssms and under programmability section i can see stored procedures but i can just see TicketUpdate ' s parameters like 
 @table(nvharchar(128),Input , No default) 
@TablePK(uniqueidentifier,Input , No default)

Comment: To see what query gets sent, use the SQL Server Profiler on the server side to track what's getting sent and executed

Comment: "I got exception after result.", maybe it would help to add the exception to the question? Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem when try to modify stored procedure somewhere I wrote wrong.
But I still want to see what is `sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery` sending as a SQL query

```
insert into blTableName//wrong
insert into '+@table+'//right
```

Comment: Have you tried using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler ?